# Polar coordinates relative to an oriented origin

Tags: 3d, rotation, linear-algebra, projection, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to map a circular plane onto a spherical surface, but I've found a problem that I'm not able to resolve. I've successfully projected every point of the plane (that is tangent to the sphere) onto the sphere itself, now I'm trying to calculate polar coordinates of every projected vertex to generate some kind of heightmap. The problem is that the center of the sphere (that can be considered the space origin) can rotate, so I'm able to calculate polar coordinates of the center of the plane, but I can't figure out how to get other plane's polar coordinates.

The situation is, briefly:
There is a sphere in the origin of axes with origin S that can rotate
There is a circular plane with center C and generic (x,y,z) coordinates, or (R, theta, sigma), always tangent to the sphere

Does anyone knows how to get vertices polar coordinates relative to O?

EDIT:
Alternatively, I can calculate quaternion from O orientation to OC and then, maybe, calculate a quaternion X and Y direction to get the vertices. But I'm not sure if it's possible and how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by *the center of the sphere can rotate*? Do you mean "the spherical coordinate system can rotate arbitrarily about this center" or "the center can move"?

Comment: The center can move and rotate, imagine as it was a planet that can tilt around its axis. So the center of the sphere can be considered as (0,0,0) but it can also rotate

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the relevant terminology, because a point in space cannot *rotate* as such - it can only move along some path. By the above I believe you mean that a set of coordinate axes, which are fixed with respect to features on the Earth's surface, can rotate about its center.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for my bad english, you believed correctly anyway